# India hourly/daily/weekly wages data

Tags: data-request, wages

I am trying to find wage data on Indians. In particular, I want to find  relatively new information on the average daily/weekly/hourly (slight preference for the weekly, but could live with any alternative) of college educated Indian male wages.

I have found this

- https://m.rbi.org.in/scripts/AnnualPublications.aspx?head=Handbook%20of%20Statistics%20on%20Indian%20States, but it only has information on rural workers, and
- this: https://www.ilo.org/wcmsp5/groups/public/---asia/---ro-bangkok/---sro-new_delhi/documents/publication/wcms_638305.pdf, but its data is from 2008.

I could even use the 2008 data if I would have access to a level of earnings index from India to update the data to a later year, but alas, I do not have that either.

I also took a look at the India Human Development Survey (IHDS), but I think that's also a bit too old.

Any tips much welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked CMIE CPHS database?It provides monthly wage income.
https://consumerpyramidsdx.cmie.com/

Comment: hey @chris jude, this is super useful! I am afraid that CMIE has a price tag that goes way above what I am willing to pay. CMIE did link to an academic paper that sort of gives me what I wanted. Cheers! :)

Comment: I am keeping the question open for a while longer to see if any other options pop up. In particular, I would like to get weekly/monthly wage data.

Comment: This might be also useful for you. CMIE is paid data. NSSO is available and is widely used in literature - India - Employment and Unemployment, July 2011- June 2012, NSS 68th Round. http://www.microdata.gov.in/nada43/index.php/catalog/127. Although I am not quite sure whether it will serve the purpose, please also check PLFS data available in the same website

Answer (score 1):

Following @Chris Jude's clue, I found this paper: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/13504851.2022.2141438

Maiti, A. (2022). Heterogeneous impact of COVID-19 pandemic on individual income across industries. Applied Economics Letters, 1-8.

Table 1 of the paper has average annual wages by industry along with sample sizes. This allows me to calculate a weighted mean. I can also exclude agriculture and related industries to make the sample more "urban" and "educated".